# О построении функции

Tags: python, объекты

Функция g(t) = e**(-t)sin(pi*t)
Перевожу на питон:

```
from cmath import exp, sin
def g(t):
    value = exp**(-t)*sin(pi*t)
    return value
```

Ошибка:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'float'.
```

Как это можно обойти? Спасибо

Comment: Степень нужно брать от числа а не от обьетка

Answer (score 3):

1. определите `pi`

   ```
    from cmath import exp, sin, pi
   ```
2. `exp` - это функция, ее возводить в степень не надо, она сама это делает

   ```
    value = exp(-t)*sin(pi*t)
   ```